# From RxJava 1 to RxJava 2

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to convert this RxJava1 code to RxJava2

```
public static Observable<Path> listFolder(Path dir, String glob) {
    return Observable.<Path>create(subscriber -> {
        try {
            DirectoryStream<Path> stream =
                    Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, glob);

            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
            Observable.<Path>from(stream).subscribe(subscriber);
        } catch (DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
            subscriber.onError(ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            subscriber.onError(ioe);
        }
    });
}
```

The thing is that in Rxjava2 I don't get a subscriber to add a new subscription to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enjoy RxJava 2 conciseness (`Flowable` is the backpressure supporting class now):

```
public static Flowable<Path> listFolder(Path dir, String glob) {
    return Flowable.using(
        () -> Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, glob),
        stream -> Flowable.fromIterable(stream),
        stream -> stream.close());
}
```

If you don't want backpressure then replace `Flowable` with `Observable`.

Comment: is this like using create or does it take backpressure and everything into account?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I've amended the answer to support backpressure.